# Python sklearn show loss values during training

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want check my loss values during the training time so I can observe the loss at each iteration. So far I haven't found an easy way for scikit learn to give me a history of loss values, nor did I find a functionality already within scikit to plot the loss for me.

If there was no way to plot this, it'd be great if I could simply fetch the final loss values at the end of classifier.fit.

Note: I am aware of the fact that some solutions are closed form. I'm using several classifiers which do not have analytical solutions, such as logistic regression and svm.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you want exactly.

Comment: Is this any close to what you are asking for? http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.log_loss.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So I couldn't find very good documentation on directly fetching the loss values per iteration, but I hope this will help someone in the future:

```
old_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = mystdout = StringIO()
clf = SGDClassifier(**kwargs, verbose=1)
clf.fit(X_tr, y_tr)
sys.stdout = old_stdout
loss_history = mystdout.getvalue()
loss_list = []
for line in loss_history.split('\n'):
    if(len(line.split("loss: ")) == 1):
        continue
    loss_list.append(float(line.split("loss: ")[-1]))
plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.arange(len(loss_list)), loss_list)
plt.savefig("warmstart_plots/pure_SGD:"+str(kwargs)+".png")
plt.xlabel("Time in epochs")
plt.ylabel("Loss")
plt.close()
```

This code will take a normal SGDClassifier(just about any linear classifier), and intercept the `verbose=1` flag, and will then split to get the loss from the verbose printing. Obviously this is slower but will give us the loss and print it.

Comment: Do you have implementation with logistic regression?

Answer (score 3):

Use `model.loss_curve_`.

You can use the `verbose` option to print the values on each iteration but if you want the actual values, this is not the best way to proceed because you will need to do some hacky stuff to parse them.

It's true, the documentation doesn't mention anything about this attribute, but if you check in the source code, you may notice that one of `MLPClassifier` base classes (`BaseMultilayerPerceptron`) actually [defines an attribute `loss_curve_`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/1495f69242646d239d89a5713982946b8ffcf9d9/sklearn/neural_network/multilayer_perceptron.py#L287) where it stores the values on each iterarion.

As you get all the values in a list, plotting should be trivial using any library.

Notice that this attribute is only present while using a stochastic solver (i.e. `sgd` or `adam`).

Answer (score 3):

I just adapted and updated the answer from @OneRaynyDay. Using [context manager](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html) is way more elegant.

**Defining Context Manager:**

```
import sys
import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class DisplayLossCurve(object):
  def __init__(self, print_loss=False):
    self.print_loss = print_loss

  """Make sure the model verbose is set to 1"""
  def __enter__(self):
    self.old_stdout = sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = self.mystdout = io.StringIO()
  
  def __exit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    sys.stdout = self.old_stdout
    loss_history = self.mystdout.getvalue()
    loss_list = []
    for line in loss_history.split('\n'):
      if(len(line.split("loss: ")) == 1):
        continue
      loss_list.append(float(line.split("loss: ")[-1]))
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(np.arange(len(loss_list)), loss_list)
    plt.xlabel("Epoch")
    plt.ylabel("Loss")

    if self.print_loss:
      print("=============== Loss Array ===============")
      print(np.array(loss_list))
      
    return True
```

**Usage:**

```
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDRegressor

model = SGDRegressor(verbose=1)

with DisplayLossCurve():
  model.fit(X, Y)

# OR

with DisplayLossCurve(print_loss=True):
  model.fit(X, Y)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

# Create and train your logistic regression model
model = LogisticRegression(solver='sag', max_iter=2000, random_state=27, warm_start=True)

# Lists to store iteration and loss values
iterations = []
loss_values = []

for i in range(model.max_iter):
    model.fit(x_train, y_train)
    iterations.append(i + 1)

    # Calculate the loss using the log loss (cross-entropy) function
    probas = model.predict_proba(x_train)
    loss = -np.mean(np.log(np.choose(y_train, probas.T)))
    loss_values.append(loss)

# Create a plot of the loss function
plt.figure()
plt.plot(iterations, loss_values, marker='o', linestyle='-')
plt.title('Loss Function Over Iterations')
plt.xlabel('Iterations')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.grid()
plt.show()

# Make predictions on the test data
predictions = model.predict(x_test)

# Compare the predictions to the actual labels (y_test)
print("Predictions:", predictions)
print("Actual Labels (y_test):", y_test)
```