# what is the score in plot_learning_curve of scikit learn?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

In scikit learn, I make a regression of Boston House Price and get the following learning curve. But what is meaning of score(y axis) in regression? [image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Graph visualizes the learning curves of the model for both training and validation as the size of the training set is increased. The shaded region of a learning curve denotes the uncertainty of that curve (measured as the standard deviation). The model is scored on both the training and testing sets using **R2**, the coefficient of determination.

It depends on what do you want to measure, you can choose anything from following chart(may be any other metric not present here):
[image]

Reference:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html

Comment: Do you know how to get the loss value each iteration? I saw an answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44443479/python-sklearn-show-loss-values-during-training). The answer uses verbose=1, but there is not the argument verbose in many methods such as linear regression.

Comment: The default scoring option for regression is R2 indeed, but I figured this by comparing learning_curve() output with my R2 computation. The sklearn article cited doesn't mention it.