# SGDClassifier save loss from every iteration to array

Tags: scikit-learn, gradient-descent

When I train a SGDClassifier in scikit-learn, I can print out the loss value from every iteration (setting verbosity). How to store the values into an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying the answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44443479/python-sklearn-show-loss-values-during-training/).

```
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist

(x_tr, y_tr), (x_te, y_te) = mnist.load_dataset()
x_tr, x_te = x_tr.reshape(-1, 784), x_te.reshape(-1, 784)
```

Intercept the printed output by the `SGDClassifier`

```
old_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = mystdout = StringIO()
```

Set the model to print its output by setting `verbose` to `1`.

```
clf = SGDClassifier(verbose=1)
clf.fit(x_tr, y_tr)
```

Get the output of SGDClassifier verbosity

```
sys.stdout = old_stdout
loss_history = mystdout.getvalue()
```

Create a list to store the loss values

```
loss_list = []
```

Append the loss values printed which is stored in loss_history

```
for line in loss_history.split('\n'):
    if(len(line.split("loss: ")) == 1):
        continue
    loss_list.append(float(line.split("loss: ")[-1]))
```

Just to show the graph

```
plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.arange(len(loss_list)), loss_list)
plt.xlabel("Time in epochs"); plt.ylabel("Loss")
plt.show()
```

To save the loss values to an array,

```
loss_list = np.array(loss_list)
```