# sklearn logistic regression loss value during training

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

Is there a way to obtain loss value at each iteration while training a logistic regression?

[Python sklearn show loss values during training](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44443479/python-sklearn-show-loss-values-during-training) has an working example for SGDRegressor however not working for logistic regression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should change the parameter verbose or remove it. It works for me when you remove it, by default, "verbose=0".

```
old_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = mystdout = StringIO()
clf = LogisticRegression()
clf.fit(X_tr, y_tr)
sys.stdout = old_stdout
loss_history = mystdout.getvalue()
loss_list = []
for line in loss_history.split('\n'):
    if(len(line.split("loss: ")) == 1):
        continue
    loss_list.append(float(line.split("loss: ")[-1]))
plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.arange(len(loss_list)), loss_list)
plt.savefig("warmstart_plots/pure_LogRes:"+".png")
plt.xlabel("Time in epochs")
plt.ylabel("Loss")
plt.close()
```

Comment: Did this work for anyone? Didn't work for me in a Jupyter notebook. Also, what is the point about using `**params` here instead of `**kwargs`? There is no mention of those variables, so they could be literally anything. The only parameter that I could see being relevant here is `verbose=1` and that's not even mentioned. Wild that scikit-learn doesn't have functionality for this natively.

Comment: I rerun the code and you're right, verbose is the only relevant. Updating the code.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the workaround using `sys.stdout` unfortunately does not work for the `LogisticRegression()` class, although it does for `SGDClassifier()`.

I did get this to work by running the Python file from the terminal and piping the output to a file directly:

```
python3 logreg_train.py > terminal_output.txt
```

Then one can parse the output to extract the change in training loss.